# Flat File --> BizTalk --> Sql Server - Sequence of rows mismatch

Tags: sql, biztalk

Source Flat File getting processed from BizTalk to Sqlserver table - but after processing file in sql server order/sequence of records mismatched
as compared to source flat file

We have a source flat file "FileA" which has only one column of 80 characters.
Once imported using BizTalk --> SQL server table , Sequence of records changes in SQL server table as compared to original Flat file.

We want to maintain exact same order of rows in SQL server table as present in Flat file "FileA"

When we use normal "Import data" Wizard at SQL server , data goes in SQL server table is same order of "FileA" but not while processed from BizTalk.

Can you please give suggestion on how to get data in same order of flat file "FileA" in SQL server table using BizTalk.

Comment: Tables in SQL Server are an *unordered* set of rows. The only ordering you can rely on is that you specify in an `ORDER BY` when `SELECT`ing data.

Comment: Selecting the data from Sql server table using order by clause is not giving me records in same order as of Flat File. The requirement is to get that same order of records. Please Suggest. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: How big is you file, and r u splitting the file into individual records to insert them into sql. Can you provide some design details

Comment: Are you debatching?  As Damien* points out, SQL table data is not intrinsically ordered, you've just gotten lucky so far.  You need to first learn some basic SQL functionality, then learn what the business considers 'ordered', then decorate the data so SQL Server can produce the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain the order of the records from the Flat file, create a new field that you map to using the row number to using the Interation functoid and also insert that into the database